# Camera and PictureSourceType not defined Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, camera

I am trying to get the camera working from a button but am getting errors on the commented lines below. I am using the documentation provided by Phonegap/Cordova (v2.1). Any help appreciated.

```
    var pictureSource = navigator.Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA; // Cannot read PictureSourceType of undef
    var destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI;

    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
        var placeImage = document.getElementById('placeImage');
        placeImage.src = imageURI;
        placeImage.style.display = 'block';
        console.log(imageURI);
    }

    function getPhoto() {
        navigator.Camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { //I am getting an error for this line saying camera is not defined?
             quality: 50, 
             destinationType: camera.destinationType.FILE_URI,
             sourceType: pictureSource
        });
    }

    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }
```

Comment: Can you read destinationType? Have you included cordova.js in your scripts?

Comment: Hi cggaurav, I have this in my script.  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script> I haven't included an onDeviceReady function as I am already testing my database with one just before. Is this correct? Should I be able to get the destination before I can take a picture?

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html, should be navigator.camera not navigator.Camera?

Comment: I tried that in Eclipse and I'm still getting the same error. Thanks for the typo spot though.

Comment: Its hard to figure out with just this piece of javascript what might be wrong, best if you run the quick example in http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html

Comment: I took the .CAMERA off the end of pictureSource and now the error is just showing up on the getPicture line. I know you can set different options if you want to take a photo from camera, from library etc but from my reading, just leaving it like this makes it default, meaning all three. This is in the documentation - Camera.PictureSourceType = {
    PHOTOLIBRARY : 0,
    CAMERA : 1,
    SAVEDPHOTOALBUM : 2
};

Comment: Are you updating camera permissions on the manifest? Any other StackOverflower will need more information to help you out otherwise

Comment: I'm not sure what that means but I will go check see and get back.

Comment: OK is it this that I need to alter? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>    Already in manifest. Also, I see from other posts that if you change the manifest is will  not work with PhoneGapBuild?

Comment: Hi, It is now working. When I changed my get.Picture code block with the quick example code from PhoneGap, (basically taking out the sourceType line) it started working. Success function now running and logging the path to the image in the console. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you've got "deviceready" event first. For your call to getPicture() do this:

```
navigator.Camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
         quality: 50, 
         destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
         sourceType: pictureSource
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, I was using this method and still getting the error (undefined). I can't work on my code right now, but will try this again later. Please see my last comment on the above. Maybe you could shed some light on why it would be working now, without that line. I am now getting the success function and the image path is logging to the console, so I guess it is safe enough to use this now?

Comment: I probably should add that the error still logs in the console in Eclipse. Despite that, I can take a pic with camera, show it in my html, call the success function and log path in the console. I tested this on my phone through Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on this. If you are talking about Android, you need to test on a real device. No matter you test on browser or simulator in Eclipse, it will give you Camera not defined error. I guess it is because hardware problem.